# The concert is over. Move and laugh now. It's okay."

Tags: grammar

On the way home, Mom smiles and says, "Good job, Hojin. The concert is over. Move and laugh now. It's okay."

In this context, in the last sentence, 'What does 'It' refer to? Is 'It' a dummy subject which doesn't represent at all?

1. Move and laugh now. It's okay.
2. Moving and laughing now is okay.

[Doesn't "It" refer to 'Moving and laughing now' as in #2?]

Answer (score 2):

"It" would refer to "moving and laughing", but it may be better to treat this as a little idiom that can be used to ask for or give permission.

> It's okay to cry.
>
> Is it okay if my friend comes and stays the night sometime next week?

Comment: 1. It's okay to move and laugh now. 2. It's okay moving and laughing now. 3. It's okay if you move and laugh now.  What about these sentences? Aren't they the same as "It's okay." as in my original question?

Comment: Yes, those would mean the same.